# what is optimized way to write a tsv file in windows Power shell script?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm just a newbie and a i wrote a small script to generate a tsv txt file.

### The code is

```
$("x")+ "`t" +("y") + "`t"+ $("z")| Add-Content C:\temp\DCO.txt
$i=0
$ts= Get-Date
while($i -le 1000000)
{
$x="N/A"
$y="N/A"
$z="N/A"
($x) + "`t"+ ($y)+ "`t"+ ($z)| Add-Content C:\temp\DCO.txt
$i++
}
$tf= Get-Date
```

---

It took a good amount of time. If there is some other optimized way to write a tsv file with a size of around 50mb or may be more than that.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I would use Export-CSV to do this. Collect your values to objects and export them. Ex:

```
#Create objects(think lines in a tsv) with properties and values
$o1 = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    Property1 = "Val1o1"
    Property2 = "Val2o1"
    Property3 = "Val3o1"
}

$o2 = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    Property1 = "Val1o2"
    Property2 = "Val2o2"
    Property3 = "Val3o2"
}

#Collect to array
$o = $o1, $o2

#Save to TSV
$o | Export-Csv "c:\test.tsv" -Delimiter `t -NoTypeInformation

#Add content
$o3 = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    Property1 = "Val1o3"
    Property2 = "Val2o3"
    Property3 = "Val3o3"
}

#Append to TSV-file
$o3 | Export-Csv "c:\test.tsv" -Delimiter `t -NoTypeInformation -Append

#To read file back to PowerShell objects
$a = Import-Csv "C:\test.tsv" -Delimiter `t
```

Test.tsv

```
"Property1" "Property2" "Property3"
"Val1o1"    "Val2o1"    "Val3o1"
"Val1o2"    "Val2o2"    "Val3o2"
"Val1o3"    "Val2o3"    "Val3o3"
```